# Terraform Objects in Buckets

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create 3 buckets containing the same 3 objects like the following:

- com.dev.example <-- bucket

  - Archive
  - Software
  - Input
- com.cert.example <-- bucket

  - Archive
  - Software
  - Input
- com.prod.example <-- bucket

  - Archive
  - Software
  - Input

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

I have the following code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "app-bucket" {
  count  = "${length(var.buckets)}"
  bucket = "com.${element(var.buckets, count.index)}.cami"
  acl    = "private"

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.global_product}-${var.global_account_number}"
    contact     = "${var.global_contact}"
    product     = "${var.global_product}"
    environment = "${var.global_environment}-${var.local_environment}"
    role        = "server-bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "app-bucket-objects" {
    count  = "${length(var.bucket_objects)}"
    bucket = "${element(aws_s3_bucket.app-bucket.*.bucket, count.index)}"
    acl    = "private"
    key    = "${element(var.bucket_objects, count.index)}"
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

with the following variables

```
buckets                 = ["dev", "cert", "int"]
bucket_objects          = ["Archive", "Software", "Input"]
```

Which produces

```
+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.0
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.dev.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Archive"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.1
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.cert.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Software"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.2
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.int.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Input"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of doing nested loops of things in Terraform so you might just have to duplicate the configuration for the thing that makes most sense. In your case I'd probably loop through the buckets to make sure that all the buckets are definitely the same but define the bucket object multiple times for each of the objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs code gym.

This should work, the rest codes are same.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "app-bucket-objects" {
  # So you need totally 3 * 3 = 9 bucket objects
  count  = "${length(var.buckets) * length(var.bucket_objects)}"

  # / is division, so you get 0,0,0,1,1,1 ...
  bucket = "${element(aws_s3_bucket.app-bucket.*.bucket, count.index / length(var.bucket_objects))}"

  acl    = "private"

  # % returns reminder, so you get 0,1,2,0,1,2 ...
  key    = "${element(var.bucket_objects, count.index % length(var.bucket_objects) )}"

  source = "/dev/null"
}
```

Output

```
+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.0
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.dev.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Archive"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.1
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.dev.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Software"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.2
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.dev.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Input"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.3
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.cert.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Archive"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.4
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.cert.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Software"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"

+ aws_s3_bucket_object.app-bucket-objects.5
    acl:                    "private"
    bucket:                 "com.cert.cami"
    content_type:           "<computed>"
    etag:                   "<computed>"
    key:                    "Input"
    server_side_encryption: "<computed>"
    source:                 "/dev/null"
    storage_class:          "<computed>"
    version_id:             "<computed>"
```